# re.sub vs re.findall in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm using regex to find some numbers after certain characters. The problem that I have is that Python is not ignoring what I have outside the parentheses when I try to replace in the string, but it does when I use `re.findall`. Here's an example, where I want to replace the numbers after `g=`:

```
str = '999.33 This is an example g= 9.81 with numbers 32 in bewteen 5555'
test_find = re.findall('=\s(\d+\.?\d+)', str)
test_sub = re.sub('=\s(\d+\.?\d+)', '10', str)
print(test_find, test_sub)
```

With this I get:

```
['9.81'] 999.33 This is an example g10 with numbers 32 in bewteen
```

But I would like to replace the `g= 9.81` with `g= 10`.
I don't understand why it's working with `re.findall`.

Comment: `re.findall()` and `re.sub()` are very different beasts. Did you read their documentation? For `re.findall()`, the documentation explicitly states what happens when there are groups, and `re.sub()` replaces the whole match, always (groups give you access to substrings of the match).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
import re
str = '999.33 This is an example g= 9.81 with numbers 32 in bewteen 5555'
print( re.sub(r'(?<=\=)(\s+\d+\.?\d+)', '10', str) )   #Lookbehind
```

**Output:**

```
999.33 This is an example g=10 with numbers 32 in bewteen 5555
```